# question about using the polymorphic association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How guys
I'm new to rails, here's my code:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :videoable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Drummer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos,:as => :videoable
end


class Cymbal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :videoable
end
```

From this point I can use the `drummer.videos` to get all the video that belong to drummer, 
But I can't use  video.drummer to get who is the video belongs to.

of course I can use video.where(:videoable_id => '1', :videoable_type => 'drummer') to get the to find the exact drummer record, but I think there must be a elegant to do that in rails, right?

and one more question, I want to improve this association, video and drummer, video and cymbal should be many-to-many, sometime there are more than 1 drummer or 1 cymbal in one video, so it makes sense do it this way. how can I do this?

Comment: I saw lots of similar questions and none of elegant ways to solve

Comment: If `video.videoable.class` is `Drummer` then does `video.videoable.<some drummer attribute>` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always a one-to-many relationship that you want (a video can at most have one drummer), you can add these lines to your Video model:

```
belongs_to :drummer, :class_name => "Drummer", :foreign_key => "videoable_id"
belongs_to :cymbal, :class_name => "Cymbal", :foreign_key => "videoable_id"
```

Rails will figure out what class the foreign key maps to and fetch the correct entry.

Comment: Your answer looks promising, I'll try it out.

Comment: Wow, it really work, but the only problem is it doesn't know the videoable_type well, if video instance has videable_type = '2'(which belongs to cymbal, not drummer), but the videable_id = '1', although , call video.cymbal, I can get the right answer, but I can still call video.drummer, it return the drummer record with id = '1', which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `video.videoable` and many-to-many join tables.

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Thanks for sharing me these links, BTW apidock.com is a unique site, how do you use it?

Answer (score 1):

If your `Drummer` and `Cymbal` models are similar, you might consider using STI instead of polymorphism. Define a new model with at `type` column to act as a parent, and add the `has_many` association, then add the child models:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subject_videos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :videos, :through => :subject_videos
end

class Drummer < Subject
end

class Cymbal < Subject
end
```

Add a SubjectVideo model with foreign keys `subject_id` and `video_id`. Then make your Video model associate through it:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subject_videos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subjects, :through => :subject_videos
end
```

Now you have a many-to-many association.

```
d = Drummer.create
d.videos # []
d.videos.create(:name=>"Stompin' at the Savoy")
v = Video.find_by_name("Stompin' at the Savoy")
v.subjects # [Drummer]
```

The primary drawback of this approach is that Drummer and Cymbal are now stored in the same table, which can be undesirable if they share few columns.

If still need a many-to-many relationship using polymorphism, also take a look at [has_many_polymorphs](https://github.com/fauna/has_many_polymorphs).

Comment: wow,Thanks for your comprehensive answer, now I know the STI, but in my case I can't put the Drummer and Cymbal in the same table, BTW your link is so cool, I'm so excited to check out, it's good to know some one working on same thing that you are interested about